# Proprietary DVD/Blu-ray Software Drivers for Ubuntu 18.04.02

Tags: dvd

Do you have a reliable source for proprietary DVD/Blu-ray Software Drivers? I've tried several times contacting Fluendo Multimedia, but have not received a response to date.

Comment: Why do you need drivers?